# Query on Angular resource returns all elements instead of the ones matching the parameter string

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have the following function:

```
$scope.filterByWeek = function(week) {
    Results.query({ week: week }, function(results){
        $scope.results = results;
    });
};
```

In my view I call the function in an ng-click:

```
<li ng-repeat="week in calendarWeeks">
    <span ng-click="filterByWeek(week)">{{week}}</span>
```

When I click on one of the weeks, it just returns all of them, as if the `{ week: week }` condition wasn't even present.

However, if I use a `filter` and explicitly say `| filter:{ week: 'one' }` for instance, it works just fine. I don't want to use this approach though because it loads everything in the DOM. I want the controller to pass through what is defined by the `filterByWeek` function.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

The resultsService if needed:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Results', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/results/:_id');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All fixed:

```
var query = Results.find();
if (req.query.week) {
    query.where({ week: req.query.week })
} else {
    query.limit(20);
}
```

Missing from my express route. Forget about that connection.